# Oracle APEX and Images

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have two servers A and B.

I have an ORACLE server (19c) on Server A (Centos),
On Server B (Centos) I have ORDS (TOMCAT) and a webServer on which APEX works and which connects to the ORALCE database on Server A.

I have a lot of pictures, I want to keep them in the database (yes, if the pictures are important, they should be kept in the database within the integrity).

I want these photos to be on server B where there are static files for APEX in the Images folder (subfolder "my photos").

Is there any mechanism to send photos from the database to a remote server (synchronize), or do I have to work on my own to send photos via FTP for example?

Comment: You can upload all photos in a database an create an api rest with ords to solve the requirement. I didn't know something to synchronize media unfortunately

Comment: you won't be able to synchronise unless both severs are sharing a filesystem, that could be an option in the case you want to synchronise. However, as your pictures are in the database, the best option is to use a RESTfull service.

Comment: here is a nice example https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/11/yet-another-rest-post-and-get-blobs/